# Autoencoder + K-means for clustering

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cluster-analysis, autoencoder

I am implementing a feed-forward neural network for a specific clustering problem.
I'm not sure if it is possible or even makes sense, but the network consists of multiple layers followed by a clustering layer (say, k-means) used to calculate the clustering loss.
The NN layers act as a feature extractor, while the last layer is only used to calculate the loss (for example, by calculating the similarity score among different data points).
Actually, this network architecture is part of a bigger auto-encoder similar to what is discussed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.07472.pdf).

The question here is can I define a custom loss function in Tensorflow/Keras that receives the output of NN and compute the clustering loss? And how?
[image]